# Is it possible in wordpress previous post next post on all pages?

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the code I working on:

```
<?php previous_posts_link('<img src="imageURL.com/image1.png" style="width: 250px;float: left;" />'); ?>

<?php next_posts_link('<img src="imageURL.com/image2.png" style="width: 250px;float: left;" />'); ?>
```

Which works great, except it only shows both images on the middle pages, but not on the first and last pages. This makes sense because there is not a previous page on the first page and not a next page on the last page. My problem is that the images look weird without the other image on the page. What I would like to do is make the image appear on the first page and link to the last post and vice-versa on the last page. I tried using the [Latest Post Link plug-in](https://wordpress.org/plugins/latest-post-link/). and this code:

```
<a href="<?php latestpostlink_permalink() ?>" title="Most Recent Post">Latest &gt;|</a>
```

But then three images show up. I tried putting conditional statements to only make this image show up on the first page, but I can not think or find the right variable name to tell what page I am on. I am a bit new to wordpress. Any help is appreciated so thanks in advance!

Jeremy

Answer (score 1):

Open single.php and rename previous_post_link to custom_previous_post_link and next_post_link to custom_next_post_link.  Then past the following into your functions.php file:

```
function custom_adjacent_post_link($format, $link, $in_same_cat = false, $excluded_categories = '', $previous = true)
    {
    if ($previous && is_attachment()) $post = get_post(get_post()->post_parent);
      else $post = get_adjacent_post($in_same_cat, $excluded_categories, $previous);
    if (!$post)
        {
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
        );
        if ($previous) $args['order'] = 'DESC';
          else $args['order'] = 'ASC';
        $adjposts = get_posts($args);
        $post = $adjposts[0];
        }
    $title = $post->post_title;
    if (empty($post->post_title)) $title = $previous ? __('Previous Post') : __('Next Post');
    $title = apply_filters('the_title', $title, $post->ID);
    $date = mysql2date(get_option('date_format') , $post->post_date);
    $rel = $previous ? 'prev' : 'next';
    $string = '<a href="' . get_permalink($post) . '" rel="' . $rel . '">';
    $inlink = str_replace('%title', $title, $link);
    $inlink = str_replace('%date', $date, $inlink);
    $inlink = $string . $inlink . '</a>';
    $output = str_replace('%link', $inlink, $format);
    $adjacent = $previous ? 'previous' : 'next';
    echo apply_filters("{$adjacent}_post_link", $output, $format, $link, $post);
    }
function custom_previous_post_link($format = '&laquo; %link', $link = '%title', $in_same_cat = false, $excluded_categories = '')
    {
    custom_adjacent_post_link($format, $link, $in_same_cat, $excluded_categories, true);
    }
function custom_next_post_link($format = '%link &raquo;', $link = '%title', $in_same_cat = false, $excluded_categories = '')
    {
    custom_adjacent_post_link($format, $link, $in_same_cat, $excluded_categories, false);
    }
```

Comment: Quick question. Should my previous_post_link and next_post_link be in the single.php file? Right now it is not. It is actually in the archive.php file.

Comment: Typically single.php is used for single posts.  Archive could be used as an archive template.  It really depends on your theme and how the designer made the structure.  If you make the change in the archive.php file and it works, well then there's nothing more to do.

Comment: For some reason it does not work when I change the archive.php file. It actually removes the buttons and everything below them(footer etc...).

Comment: Without knowing the error you're receiving or if the change has been implemented correctly I don't know what to tell you.  I tested the code on 2 different sites before commenting to make sure it worked and it worked fine for me.  Double check everything once more.